# Cant get then to trigger after when

Tags: jquery, promise, .when

The following code should be straightforward

```
//Generic success routine, let the developer know, store the results
function genericSuccess( _data , textStatus , jqXHR )
{
  data[this.url] = _data;
}

jQuery.when(  $.ajax({ url: metaKey, success: genericSuccess }) , 
              $.ajax({ url: docsKey, success: genericSuccess }) ).then( console.log( "Then!" ) );
```

But `console.log('Then')` keeps triggering first. Why ? This does not work with 1.7.2 and 1.8.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't passing a callback to `.then`, instead you're just console.logging *"Then!"* immediately.

What you want is:

```
.then( function(){
    console.log( "Then!" );
});
```